# Automating a survey utilizing SQL data and abstracting results

Tags: t-sql, sharepoint, survey, surveymonkey

At my workplace there is a weekly test taken by employees using a web application which collects results in a SQL database. My ask is ***How can I use these results and create a survey on survey monkey/SharePoint etc. that they can take and feed the results back in to SQL?*** The survey would only have to be tailored to get feedback only on incorrect results collected by the test. If I could do this with a data driven survey using a query it seems manageable. Just not sure what web application would be the most efficient to use. Or even Report Builder?

Comment: this doesnt look like a question to me. You didnt define the issue properly.

Comment: It is italicized. I need a sql data driven survey that collects results and deposits them.

Comment: i have read it 10 times, I am still lost. use the result, create a survey and feed the results back to SQL. Is this question about transfering data to/from survey monkey to SQL database?

Comment: Yes, if that is the right platform to use.

Comment: Right now you'd have have to build your own application on top of the SurveyMonkey API to listen for and/or fetch incoming response data, transform the data, and insert it into SQL.
We (SurveyMonkey) are nearing completion of an ETL integration with https://www.singer.io/, which should cover your SurveyMonkey to SQL needs, if you're willing to wait till early next year.